# c++ ignore input line from user

Tags: c++, input

I got a simple loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<n*2; i++) {
        if (i < n) getline(cin,text[i]);
        else getline(cin, trash);
    }
```

`n` is the amount of lines I need to save in the `text` array, but the program gets `n*2` amount of lines half of which I need to ignore. So what I did is I stored the first `n` lines into the array and then "throwed away"(`getline(cin, trash);`) the other `n` lines that I don't need. It works, but is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Instead of having a dummy `trash` (which is a fine option, by the way), you could instead do `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')` to throw the line away without populating a dummy variable.

Comment: In addition to Eljay's suggestion, I would suggest using 2 separate loops for this task: `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { getline(cin, text[i]); } for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { cin.ignore(...); }`

Comment: `{ getline(cin, i < n ? trash:text[i] ); }`   haha Really both halves can go to trash for sure